Do weapon effects on stamina consumption across the whole party, stack if multiples are wielded?
I have multiple Waveriding Whirls, if I have two or more people using it in my party, does the "Decreases Stamina Consumption by 15%" multiply or something into even more Stimina Consumption reduction?
And if it doesn't for this weapon are there other weapons with Stamina / Speed effects that affect the whole party, that are worthwhile to wear on multiple people?
